# why does replacement rule not work

Tags: replacement

Why does the following replacement rule not work?

```
term = x^2/y^2 + x^3/y^3

term /. u_^p_/v_^p_ -> z^p
```

I expected it to return `z^2 + z^3`.

Comment: take a look at `FullForm[term]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 term /. Times[Power[x_, n_], Power[y_, m_]] /; m == -n :> z^n
```

or

```
 term /. (x_^n_) (y_^m_) /; m == -n :> z^n
```

> z^2 + z^3

Answer (score 3):

Check full form of the summand in your term, `x^2 / y^2`:

```
x^2 / y^2 // FullForm

Times[Power[x,2], Power[y,-2]]
```

Compare this to `FullForm` or your pattern:

```
u_^p_ / v_^p_ // FullForm

Times[
  Power[Pattern[u, Blank[]], Pattern[p, Blank[]]],
  Power[Pattern[v, Blank[]], Times[-1, Pattern[p, Blank[]]]]]
```

You may notice there is a difference between internal representations of `-2` and `-p`: the first one is `Integer` expression (that is, expression with Head `Integer`), the second one is `Times` expression, since it's a product of `-1` and `p` (in your case it's `Pattern[p, Blank[]]`, rather than simply `p`). This is why there is no match.

In general, use of complicated expressions in patterns requires some care. This will not work:

```
(1/3) /. (1/a_) :> a

1 / 3
```

Much like in your example, `1/3` is “a straightforward number”, and as such is treated not like a more general expression `(1/a_)`:

```
1/3 // FullForm

Rational[1, 3]
```

The pattern `1/a_` is not a rational number, hence it's not represented as `Rational` expression, and again, there's no match.